# Progress bar with background worker

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I was hoping for some help with my backgroundworker as I just cant get it to work.  Basically I have a backgroundworker which does a few tasks but I'm trying to implement a progress bar and a label.  I'm going to set the maximum value of the progress bar to 10 and then have it updating as I move with each task, also I'm thinking of a label with the progress bar which will display the progress ie

```
Pb value = 2
20% completed

Pb value = 6
60% completed
```

and so on.

So far I have this for the coding.

Update* Thanks lars fr your help.

So just a quick question would the do work event be like so?

```
Private Sub BGWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, _
                            ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) _
                            Handles BGWorker.DoWork
  For i as Integer = 1 to 2
    'My task code 1
    BGWorker.ReportProgress(i)
  Next

 For i as Integer = 3 to 4
    'My task code 2
    BGWorker.ReportProgress(i)
  Next

 For i as Integer = 5 to 6
    'My task code 3
    BGWorker.ReportProgress(i)
  Next

 For i as Integer = 7 to 8
    'My task code 4
    BGWorker.ReportProgress(i)
  Next

 For i as Integer = 9 to 10
    'My task code 5
    BGWorker.ReportProgress(i)
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to set the progress bar value in `DoWork` (which isn't running on the UI thread), you need to have the BackGroundWorker "report" it's progress:

```
Private Sub BGWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, _
                            ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) _
                            Handles BGWorker.DoWork
  For i as Integer = 1 to 10
    BGWorker.ReportProgress(i)
  Next
End Sub
```

Then in your `ProgressChanged` event, you can set the value of the Progress bar:

```
Private Sub BGWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                     ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
                                     Handles BGWorker.ProgressChanged
  Me.Pb1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

Comment: @JackSparrow I looked at your code, and yes, that would work.  Assuming these "tasks" do take more than 50 ms.  The `ProgressChanged` event is where you update your GUI, which is why the progress bar is getting updated over there.  That's also where you would update your label: `Me.Label1.Text = String.Format("{0} %", e.ProgressPercentage * 10)`.  Use the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to set everything back to 0 and reset the label to "Completed" or something like that.

Comment: Hi Lars, sorry I thought that the Me.Label1.Text = String.Format("{0} %", e.ProgressPercentage * 10) would go in the Do Work event underneath the BGWorker.ReportProgress(i) and NOT in the progress changed event?

Comment: @JackSparrow Nope.  DoWork is what is happening in the *background*, not on the screen.  That's where the `ReportProgress` event comes in.  When you call `ReportProgress` from `DoWork`, you are giving your screen a chance to show what's happening.  Any and all screen updates from a `BackgroundWorker` should happen in `ProgressChanged` or `RunWorkerCompleted` events.

Comment: Lars, please ignore my previous comment I understnad what you're saying now :) just one thing I have used the above coding but for some reason it only fills in around 20% of the progress bar and then completes, the maximum of my progress bar is set to 100 should it be 10?

Comment: @JackSparrow Yes, because your original code had `Pb1.Maximum = 10`.  If you use 100, then you need to report 10, 20, 30 etc instead of 1, 2, 3, etc.  You want to match your overall progress to your ProgressBar's maximum value.

Comment: Lars, I'm not sure if you are still around but I'm hitting a brick wall with my coding.  I tried what you suggested above but I have big problems where my coding is not running the once, in some cases it is running up to 6 times for each loop.  However when I remove the for and next loops and remove the progress bar the coding only runs the once? thanks

Comment: @JackSparrow You have to post a new question with the code you are using.  It's hard to understand the problem from your comment description.

Answer (score 4):

You have several problems:

1. Your code won't compile.
2. You do not create a `BackgroundWorker` anywhere.
3. You have not assigned a `ProgressChanged` event handler.
4. You do not handle any events at all.

You must do all these things to use a `BackgroundWorker`. A good beginner tutorial is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: You don't *need* a `ProgressChanged` handler, unless you are trying to actually report progress.

Comment: Perhaps add a note that clarifies: ... to *report progress* from ... rather than  ... to *use* a ...

Comment: @Kendal, if you carefully read the question, you may notice he specifically stated, several times, that he indeed did want to report progress.

Comment: Yes, but the wording of your answer is slightly inaccurate. Sorry if I'm too OCD for you :/

Comment: Dour, sorry I did not think the full coding was required so I have added it in the first post.